# Adding a composite primary key in migration using raw sql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want to add a composite primary key into a table. So I added the following raw sql query into my migration file. However, when I run rake db:setup, I did not see a primary key for the table because schema.rb was not affected by this migration. How should I make this work? Thanks.

```
class AddPrimaryKeyToTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute "ALTER TABLE table ADD PRIMARY KEY(identifier,time)"
  end

  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Update you sql query to below.

```
execute "ALTER TABLE table ADD PRIMARY KEY (identifier,time);"
```